# Using If Statement in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I want to copy a cell from a worksheet based on Unique number.

[image]

[image]

If Unique number from L is equal to NO2 column, Then I want to copy block column next to the L column.

Answer (score 0):

As you're looking left from your lookup you can't use a VLOOKUP - you need to use INDEX & MATCH....

- Match the figure in column L with the figure in column J.
  `MATCH(L2,Sheet2!$J:$J,0)`
- Return the figure from column K in the row returned by the Match.
  `=INDEX(Sheet2!$K:$K,<row number>)`

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$I:$I,MATCH(L2,Sheet2!$K:$K,0))`

*Scratch that... why have you put the columns the wrong way around?*
Just use a VLOOKUP: `=VLOOKUP(L2,Sheet2!$J$2:$K$11,2,FALSE)`